# Bootstrap Datetime Picker minute slot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the datetime picker, which works fine [plunker](http://:http://plnkr.co/edit/KEndNeUPMLhkCTu6GfPZ?p=preview). 
Now I want to know which part of code to be altered for changing the minutes slot for 15minutes like 15,30,45 instead of every minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option available in the bootstrap `timepicker` api `minuteStepping: 15`.

**JS CODE:**

```
jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    minuteStepping: 15
});
```

Live Demo @ [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/RR4hw/1416/)

Comment: Thanx for the reply.. The given fiddle is not working..It would be helpful if u can let me know how to include that in my plunker

Comment: your plunker link is not valid, may be you haven't saved your plunker before you copied the url.

Comment: actually the `datetimepicker`  plugin your using doesnt contain option for time increments. you can check the api doc here,https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker. i would suggest you to go with this plugin http://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker, refer the jsfiddle above for more understanding.

Comment: when you click on the `datetimepicker` button in the `jsfiddle`, you will see a `timer icon` at the button click that for setting time and then you can click up/down arrow for incrementing or decrementing time

Comment: But I need 15minutes slot. On clicking up and down arrows the minutes has to change as 15,30,45

Comment: i believe it is incrementing/decrementing 15 minutes from current time . are you saying you want to set the current time also to next 15th minute value before incrementing/decrementing ?

Comment: @dreamwiever: Its not from current time. User should be made to select only 15minutes slots, which means the user can view minutes as only 15,30,45 and next hour. User cannot select minutes other than these. Whenever minutes is increased/ decreased it has be only as 15,30,45

Comment: in order to do that, you need to override the current time to next 15th minute increment, you need to track the events, http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpupdate  and then change the time based on that